# Check that today's date does not exist in Cypress

Tags: typescript, automation, cypress

How can I write a method in Cypress so that first I see what today's date is (but formatted in "June 21" mode) and then the date I find with new Date() , is not visible in my test?

Example of code (not spelled correctly):

```
const today = new Date(some format);
cy.contains(today).should('not.visible');
```

Also can i use something like [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) library?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You'll use the `format` and pass in `MMMM` to get the month full name (ie August) along with `dd` to get the day of the month. Then pass that formatted date into your `.contains()`.

NOTE: you can pass a selector as the first argument in the [`.contains()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains#Selector) for better filtering or it will search the entire page for the date format which may exist.

```js
import { format } from 'date-fns'

var todaysDate = format(new Date(), "MMMM dd") // todays' date 'June 21'

cy.contains(todaysDate) // you can pass a selector as 1st arg for better query
  .should('not.be.visible') // you can sub 'not.exist' to check it does not exist in DOM
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```js
const today = new Date()
const month = today.toLocaleString('default', {month: 'long'}) //June
const date = today.getDate() //21
cy.contains(month + ' ' + date).should('not.be.visible') //checks 'June 21' is not visible
```